# undefined method when calling a method in a model of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods

I keep getting undefined method for when I call a certain method from my Model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def update!
     request_info
  end
  def request_info
     return "hmmm"
  end
end
```

request_info inside of update! is not defined
I've tried making it self.request_info as well but that doesn't work either

Comment: Are you doing an instance of a user before calling it? I mean `User.first.update!`

Comment: How are you calling `update!`?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to call a method in rails.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’ for #<Foo:0x1e820>
```

Are you doing the same? I have taken this example from [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/). Take a look at that page for details.

Answer (score 0):

update! is a bad choice for a method name: update is already defined as a (private) method on ActiveRecord::Base - that might lead to confusion.

```
>> u = User.last
>> u.update
NoMethodError: private method `update' called for #<User:0x007ff862c9cc48>
```

but apart from that you code works perfectly fine when I try it in the console:

```
>> u = User.last
>> u.update!
=> "hmmm"
```